# .htaccess with .htpasswd on site root causes redirect loop

Tags: .htaccess, authentication, redirect, htpasswd

I want to temporarily password-protect a site.

I have an .htaccess file in the site root containing:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Example Site Name"
AuthUserFile /home/my_username/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

This throws up a login window when I access [example.com](http://example.com), however, when I authenticate I get a 310 error:

> This webpage has a redirect loop
>
> The webpage at http://example.com/ has resulted in too
>   many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing
>   third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a
>   server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.
>
> Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many
>   redirects.

Now, hitting example.com gives me this error every time without asking me to authenticate.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your httpd config you probably haven't got any error documents defined, so it is trying to return you to the base page, which throws an error, rinse, repeat.

try adding:

`ErrorDocument 401 /[path_to_file]/error.html`
`ErrorDocument 403 /[path_to_file]/error.html`

to your .htaccess file. Of course, make sure those simple error.html files exist too.